# Grant Access to AWS S3 bucket from specific IP without credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I do not want to make my S3 bucket publicly accessible. But I expect it to be accessible from my local organization network without the AWS CLI or any credentials. How can I achieve it?.

I tried bucket policy with principal as * and source IP as the public IP of organization network.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the correct way to do it.

From [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"}
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think this will not work as i faced similar problem once , due to S3 being designed by default to allow any IP address access. So to block IP's you would have to specify denies explicitly in the policy instead of allows.

Comment: By default, content in Amazon S3 is private. The above will grant access to `GetObject` for that bucket from that IP address. If there is no other Bucket Policy, and objects have private ACLs, then the content will otherwise remain private.

Comment: I just performed a test and can confirm that the above bucket policy is sufficient, presuming that the objects have private ACLs and the objects are accessed anonymously.

Comment: Yes I tried the same solution long while ago and failed I was updated this from aws support team back then ( we were trying to do it from within VPC before private endpoints were there)

Comment: I read your comment can you tell me which would be better solution security wise , I would also want to learn whats best !

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. The `Deny` will block _everybody_ from the bucket if they are not in the CIDR range. If that is the intention, then that is fine. However, if the intention is to grant anonymous access to a particular CIDR range, while also permitting IAM policies to grant additional access to specific people (eg Administrators), then it would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

**If the intention is to grant anonymous access to a particular CIDR range, while also permitting IAM policies to grant additional access to specific people (eg Administrators), then this would not be appropriate.**

IF you were to follow the initial example laid out by the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) - you’ll end up with a policy that probably looks similar to this.

```
{
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "x.x.x.x/xx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What you’re going to find, after banging your head on the table a few times, is that this policy does not work. There does not appear to be an implied deny rule with S3 buckets (similar to how IAM access policies are setup).

**By default accounts are restricted from accessing S3 unless they have been given access via policy. 
However, S3 is designed by default to allow any IP address access. So to block IP's you would have to specify denies explicitly in the policy instead of allows.**

Once You learn this - the policy is easy to adjust. You just flipp around the policy from allowing access from only my IP address to **denying access** from everywhere that was **NOT my IP address**.

```
{
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "xxx.x.x/xx"
                }
            }
        }
    ] }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Be careful -- the second policy would block _any user_ from being able to interact with the bucket if they are not in that CIDR range, including Administrators.